# How to scan a mp3 for silence

Tags: ios, core-audio

I writing an iOS app that needs to identify periods of silence within an mp3 file downloaded from the internet.

Downloading and playing via AVAudioPlayer is no problem but I can't figure out how to get access to the actual audio frame data within the mp3 so that I can detect sound levels in order to detect silences. I've tried :-

```
NSURL *fileUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[self filename]];

ExtAudioFileRef eaf;
OSStatus err = ExtAudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(fileUrl), &eaf);
if (noErr != err)
{
   /* handle error */
  exit(-1);
}
AudioStreamBasicDescription format;
format.mSampleRate = 44100;
format.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
format.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian;
format.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
format.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
format.mBytesPerFrame = format.mChannelsPerFrame * 2;
format.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
format.mBytesPerPacket = format.mFramesPerPacket * format.mBytesPerFrame;

err = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(eaf, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(format), &format);
if (noErr != err)
{
   /* handle error */
   NSLog(@"Error: %d", err);
  exit(-1);
}
```

But it fails on the set property with error 1718449215, so I'm assuming that it won't allow me to convert from MP3 to PCM. I want to be able to preprocess the files so that I know where the silences are going to occur before playback by the user.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter APIs to convert an mp3 file into raw PCM (or .wav) data.